Dynamic Query SwiftData won't work anymore in ios 18
I used to filter using initializers like this(example):
struct ProductListView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext    
    @Query private var products: [Product]
    @State var clickOnProduct = false
    @State var productSku: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
           List(){
             ForEach(products){ product in
               VStack(){
                 //<---
               }.onTapGesture{
                  productSku = product.sku
                  clickOnProduct.toggle()
                }
             }
           }.navigationDestination(isPresented: $clickOnProduct){
             ProductDescriptionView(productSku: productSku)
            }
        }
    }

    
}


struct ProductDescriptionView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext 
    @Query var products: [Product]
    var productSku = ""
    
    
    init(productSku: String) {
        self.productSku = productSku
        let predicate = #Predicate<Product>{$0.sku == productSku}
        self._products = Query(filter: predicate)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
       
    }

}


But now when I use this method my iPhone get hot and the app freezes, even Simulator shows overload of CPU
(https://i.sstatic.net/McqcZapB.png)
That method worked fine in ios 17 but now It doesn't work anymore. Do you have any solution?
Edit. I have change the example code to be more specific. Using NavigationStack and sending a value through navigationDestination the app freezes and doesn't go to ProductDescriptionView.

What troubleshooting have you done, are you sure it's the query and not something in the view for instance? Have you tried to use Instruments to see what happens? Are you sure you haven't changed anything in the code, like something in either of the model classes?

I pass a value through NavigationDestination and use initializer of that value to use it for queries.

I don't understand exactly what that means and how it is relevant. If this is reproducible then could you create a MRE and update your question with it.

Note, you don't declare productSku in your ProductListView, where does it come from?
Your let predicate = #Predicate<Product>{$0.sku = productSku} should at least be
let predicate = #Predicate<Product>{$0.sku == productSku}.
The code you are showing now does not seem to be anything like the code you showed us before.
Can you show the code that gives you the problem.

Thanks for the observations. I already edited the example code according to your observation. The first example code was from this tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/swiftdata-sorting-and-filtering.  But now I'm just showing a part of my project code. Hope it helps and thanks for helping, I really appreciate it.

Based on this Answer
Try this approach using an intermediate property to avoid referencing the
article model in the predicate.
struct ArticleView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var articleStates: [ArticleState]
    
    let article: Article
    
    init(article: Article) {
        self.article = article
        let articleID = article.id  // <--- here
        _articleStates = Query(filter: #Predicate { $0.articleID == articleID } )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        // ... // SwiftUI view that depends on query data.
    }
}

EDIT-1:
Try a different approach than to perform
the Query inside the init. Using a simple filter,
and if required a computed property, as shown in the example code.
struct ProductDescriptionView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var allProducts: [Product]
    
    let productSku: String
    
    var products: [Product] {
        allProducts.filter{$0.sku == productSku}
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(productSku)
        List {
            ForEach(products){ product in
                Text(product.sku)
            }
        }
    }
}

Or this alternative using modelContext.fetch... in .onAppear
struct ProductDescriptionView2: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext

    let productSku: String
    @State private var products: [Product] = []

    var body: some View {
        Text(productSku)
        List {
            ForEach(products){ product in
                Text(product.sku)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<Product>(predicate: #Predicate { product in
                product.sku == productSku
            })
            do {
                products = try modelContext.fetch(fetchDescriptor)
            } catch {
                print("Failed to load data")
            }
        }
    }
}


Actually I use the method you suggested,  It worked fine on iOS 17 but not on iOS18.  My main application is that I pass a value through NavigationDestination and use initializer of that value to use it for queries.

Show enough code to reproduce your problem, including the surounding code, such as the NavigationDestination etc... Do you use a NavigationView or NavigationStack? Is this in a .sheet? Is the problem actually caused by this code or is it to do with something in the body? or the call of the ArticleView?

I already changed the example code to be more specific as you asked. I really appreciate you interest and  I hope that example helps.

Updated my answer with some alternative approaches than to perform database access in the init(...).

I really appreciate your help mate. Its a good approach. I think some things changed with new SwiftData macros and I was struggling, even got some errors like "path doesn't exist" with SwiftData. Thanks a lot.

if my answer helped you, consider accepting it by ticking the tick mark next to it, it turns green.
